# KL divergence derivation

Tags: machine-learning, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I want to understand KL divergene. Can someone please explain why we need inequality lnx[image]

Comment: I mean that what exactly we want to do?what is the goal?

Comment: Can you please explain in simple words?

Comment: The inequality $\ln(x) \leq x - 1$ is used in the $\geq$ separating the line beneath it (starting with $KL = ...$) and the following line.

Answer (score 1):

The goal is to show that the KL divergence is a valid distance metric. For this to hold, the KL divergence between two distributions must be non-negative. That is what the proof is trying to show; since at the end the conclusion is 
$$ KL \geq 0\,.$$